# Devexpress gridView context menu item click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I created a devexpress MVC gridView, in which I enabled the ContextMenu.
For the context menu I added a custom item named "Open" as below;

```
settings.FillContextMenuItems = (sender, e) => {
    e.Items.Add("Open", "ShowMeasurement");
};
```

I don't know how to add an action method for the  new added item in the context menu, and how to get the id of the selected grid row;

Comment: The "ShowMeasurement" from above should be the actiion. Just that is not working like this.

Comment: You need to register to the grid context menu item click event, then compare the clicked item name with "Open" and fire your action. See here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_ContextMenuItemClicktopic

Comment: and how can I get the clicked item name?

Comment: I registered the ContextMenuItemClick event using : settings.ClientSideEvents.ContextMenuItemClick = "show"  , and "show" is the js function where I have to check for the clicked context menu item, in order to pass the Action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I registered the `gridContextMenuItemClicked` event like this:

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.ContextMenuItemClick = "show";
```

and in the `show(s, e)` js function I verified if `e.item.name` (clicked menu item) is equal to `Open` and then specified the needed url   `window.location.href = "/Import/ShowMeasurement?";`